Continous phase transition between two channels of sine wave
I have:

Sine Frequency: 440Hz
Sample Rate: 44.1KHz
Duration: 10 seconds
Num of amplitudes: 441000
Num of channels: 2 (both of them identic wave, just different phase)

I want to make smooth transition of phase over time for 2nd channel. I achieved it, but it was discrete transition, here is mine:
0-2 sec: 0 degree
2-4 sec: 90 degree
4-6 sec: 180 degree
6-8 sec: 270 degree

Instead of discrete transition, I want to make continous transition:
From 0 sec until 10 sec, the phase is changing over time from 0 degree to 360 degree.

How do I achieve this?
Here is the picture of mine, which is discrete transition:


This answer should help you as well: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83014/21048


From 0 sec until 10 sec, the phase is changing over time from 0 degree to 360 degree.

A linear phase shift is the same thing as a change in frequency.
I think what you want is something like
$$x(t) = A\cos(\omega_0 t + 2\pi\frac{t}{10s}) $$
That is a phase offset that linearly increases by $2\pi$ in a 10 second period. However this simply another sine wave at a slightly higher frequency
$$x(t) = A\cos(\omega_0 t + 2\pi\frac{t}{10s}) =  A\cos((\omega_0 + 2\pi\frac{1}{10s})t) $$
So this just a sine wave at a frequency of $\omega_1 = (\omega_0 + 2\pi\frac{1}{10s})$.
